Code working in emulator but no on physical device
Hey guys I am trying to get user's phone number with consent in my app but the problem is that the following code is working on an emulator but not on a physical device. I am using subscriptionManager class to fetch the phone number:
MainActivity.java code:
package com.example.phonenumber;

import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SubscriptionManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView txtPhoneNumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_PHONE_NUMBERS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{READ_PHONE_NUMBERS}, 1); // Use a request code
            return;
        }


    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    public void btnGetPhoneNumber(View view) {
        // Get phone number
        SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = (SubscriptionManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        String phoneNumber = subscriptionManager.getPhoneNumber(SubscriptionManager.DEFAULT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
        txtPhoneNumber.setText(phoneNumber);

    }
}

activity_main.xml code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="74dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="252dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:onClick="btnGetPhoneNumber"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I want somebody to check whether something in my code is creating this problem or what is happening. I've checked my code and it seems absolutely fine to me.

What's the Android version of your emulator and your physical device? I think you're not handling permissions properly. Check this. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions#phone-numbers

Both on physical and emulator the Android version is 14
